# Assign `nil` to multiple variables

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I need to assign `nil` to multiple variables. I have:

```
a = nil
b = nil
c = nil
```

Which is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `a=b=c=nil`. First evaluated `c=nil`; then `b=nil`(where `nil` is returned from previous operation); last - `a=nil`.

Comment: What are the options?

Comment: "most efficient"? What do you optimize for?

Comment: If you'll try to write something like `a=b=c=[]` and after `a << 0` - all variables (`a`,`b`,`c`) will be equal `[0]`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev May be number of lines of code? :-)

Comment: Efficiency in Ruby doesn't come primary from doing things faster.  It comes from doing fewer things (e.g. using a more efficient algorithm).  At least, micro-optimizations should not be attempted until all other optimizations are exhausted and the program is still too slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It pretty much won't get any shorter than:

```
a = b = c = nil
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
a,b,c = nil,nil,nil
# or
a,b,c = [nil] * 3
```

---

You could also do the following which takes the advantage of the fact that default value of variable is `nil` if not assigned one explicitly.

```
a,b,c = nil
```

In above case, the explicit `nil` will get assigned to `a`, while `b` and `c` will get default `nil`.  Hence, its a trick that will work only for `nil`.

---

You can also have all three variables get assigned default `nil` by using dummy variable `_` as first variable in parallel assignment.

```
_,a,b,c = nil
```

Comment: And save two key strokes with `_a,b,c = _` . :)

Answer (score 1):

To assign `nil` you can use

```
a = b = c = nil
```

But remember this works only for immutable objects.

See this example:

```
a = b = c = "test"
b << "1"
a # => "test1"
```

There you may need to try:

```
a, b, c = 3.times.map{ "test" }
```